# Specflow features aren't auto-generating cs files or appearing as tests in C# Nunit project

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, specflow

(updated this post for clarity)

I am unable to create a starting point C# Specflow Nunit project (contrary to following online tutorials and videos) whereby new specflow features autogenerate cs files and appear as runnable tests.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install Visual Studio Community 2019 v16.3.5
2. Extensions > Manage Extensions: Install Specflow for VS 2019 (v2019.0.36.11860). Restart VS to accept Specflow installation on wizard.
3. New Project > Test > C# Unit Test Project (.Net Framework, C#, Windows, Test).  Name: myProject  Framework: 4.7.2
4. Delete UnitTest1.cs auto generated project file
5. From NuGet Manager for solution, add package: Specflow.NUnit v3.0.225 (select OK to make changes to solution, and accept package licences
6. Add two folders to the project: Features, StepBindings
7. An new item to Features folder: Specflow Feature File (type: Visual C# Item) name myFeature.feature

outcome:
no autogenerated feature cs file appears under the new green myFeature.feature file

solution warning: Cannot find custom tool 'SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator' on this system.  (File: myFeature.feature)

Note: Enable SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator is set to False under Tools > Options > Specflow

8. Right click on a step within myFeature.feature > generate step definitions > save as 'myFeatureSteps.cs' in StepBindings folder
   outcome: solution warnings: ScenarioContext.Current is obsolete (File: myFeature.feature lines 12, 18, 24)
9. View-Test Explorer

outcome: No tests shown, including when clicking run all (to trigger a build / discover tests / run in solution)

Further exploratory steps:

10. (required?) Added nuGet package: NUnit3TestAdapter v3.15.1
11. Updated nuGet package NUnit to v3.12.0
12. Rebuilt project, clicked runAll in testexplorer, restarted Visual Studio

final outcome: still no tests showing in runner, and auto generated code still shows with errors (ScenarioContext.Current)

packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
<package id="BoDi" version="1.4.1" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Gherkin" version="6.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="MSTest.TestFramework" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="NUnit" version="3.12.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="NUnit3TestAdapter" version="3.15.1" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="SpecFlow" version="3.0.225" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="SpecFlow.NUnit" version="3.0.225" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="System.Reflection.Emit" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net472" />
<package id="Utf8Json" version="1.3.7" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

Note: the top packages element is underlined as "not declared"?

Code to try and get project working:
https://github.com/bobjames238745/getSpecflowWorkingWithNunit

Comment: Check the SpecFlow settings (Tools --> Options --> SpecFlow). Make sure **Enable SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator CustomTool** is set to "True", or upgrade to SpecFlow 3 so it regenerates the feature.cs files when you build the solution.

Comment: @GregBurghardt is correct. I would upgrade to SpecFlow 3.0. You are using SpecFlow 2.2 which is now over 2 years old.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the .csproj file?

Comment: Did you close all visual studio windows after installing the SpecFlow extension, and then wait for the installer to finish before opening visual studio again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your NuGet packages, you need to install the `SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation` package before the feature.cs files will be created on-build.

Comment: Thanks for responding Greg, however, I rebuilt the minimal project from scratch (see main post steps) and am now using latest components for everything. The feature.cs file isn't auto generating and feature tests aren't showing in the runner. My SpecFlow is version 3.0.225. I've put packages.config in the main post for further reference. Many thanks

Comment: @bobjames: I rewrote my answer. Thanks for posting your packages.config file. That finally tipped me off.

Comment: Really appreciate your help in trying to get basic specflow functioning! I've added the SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation, but feature .cs files still not getting created. Also have an error after adding that package saying: SpecFlow designer codebehind generation is not compatible with MSBuild codebehind generation. The custom tool must be removed from the file. (myFeature.feature). I've uploaded the project https://github.com/bobjames238745/getSpecflowWorkingWithNunit would greatly appreciate if you're able to get specflow building and appearing in testrunner.

Comment: Just delete the feature.cs files, exclude the feature files from your project, then re-include the feature files again. See https://specflow.org/2019/updating-to-specflow-3/

Comment: Thanks - having done that, I now see the feature test appearing in the testrunner - but still no generated feature .cs file? Also there is still a ScenarioContext.Current is obsolete error from the stock generated steps.cs file, but I guess that's another issue. Here's a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/6Qo159z.png

Comment: I've added stock sample feature file and step code (and selenium packages) and the test runs! Thank you. Also adding a second feature file, results in a second test found! Where is the source .cs file generated? I was expecting it nested under the feature file. Thanks for getting me working!

Comment: @bobjames: Nested feature.cs files no longer exist. If you click "Show All Files" in the Solution Explorer toolbar, you will see the feature.cs files, but they are no longer included in the solution.